# When is a matrix called well-ordered?

Tags: matrices, elementary-set-theory

We have a quick question, looking for information and/or references links.

Is there a more specific mathematical definition/criteria for when matrices can be called *well ordered* or *totally ordered*? In general any definitions/links on the type of *ordering* of a matrix are welcome.

I consciously used the term *ordering* to avoid confsusion: we are not talking about the "*the order of a matrix*".

Thanks in advance

Comment: then what kind of order are you talking about?

Comment: @IttayWeiss something along the lines of [$\geq$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory). That is, a notion of "greater than" which makes sense for matrices, and agrees with matrix addition and hopefully matrix multiplication.

Comment: The space of real valued matrices of a given order $M(p,q)$ can be identified with $\mathbb{R}^{pq}$ on which it is easy to write down orderings. [Ordered vector spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_vector_space) are pretty well studied. The difficulty, of course, is with "multiplication". Even in $\mathbb{R}$ multiplication interacts weirdly with order: $-3 < 2$ but $(-3)^2 > 2^2$. But if you treat matrix multiplication as a linear transformation on $M(p,q)$, you can certainly say something...

Comment: As [complex numbers cannot be totally ordered](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Complex_Numbers_Cannot_be_Totally_Ordered) and complex numbers can be represented by real multiples of $2\times2$ real rotation matrices, no total orders of real or complex square matrices will respect matrix multiplication, unless we are talking about $1\times1$ real matrices (i.e. real numbers).